# how to overwrite Susy settings at certain breakpoints

Tags: grid, sass, breakpoints, susy-compass

I’m using Susy’s gallery setting at a small breakpoint and (because of mobile first CSS structure), its getting passed to the larger breakpoint and I can’t figure out how to clear/overwrite it to allow my divs to span full width.

tablet output:

```
[div] [div] [div]
```

desired desktop output:

```
[      div      ]
[      div      ]
[      div      ]
```

my attempt:

```
div {
  @include gallery(4);
  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    @include break;
    @include full;
  }
}
```

[see FIDDLE](http://sassmeister.com/gist/a062d22d1c5925fd93eb)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you already resolved this by now, but since I came up against the same issue I thought I'd post my solution.

Add the following mixin:

```
@mixin reset-gallery {
  &:nth-child(1n) {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: gutter();
  }

  &:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

and then reset your divs as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  @include reset-gallery;
  @include span(full);
}
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8d369e90d5e4e3d3ca64). It might not work in all situations, but it worked for me and seems to work for your case also.